# ReactJS vs Cordova conflict on resolving js/css sources. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, cordova

When I build my app for reactJS, index.html loads some js/css files but the sources break Cordova. It seems to be about the leading slashes and appending http: before //. Fixing them for cordova breaks React. How can I resolve this?

ReactJS wants:

- `<script src="/myApp.js">`
- `<link href="/myCss.css">`
- `<script src="//example.com/myscript.js">`

Cordova wants:

- `<script src="myApp.js">`
- `<link href="myCss.css">`
- `<script src="http://example.com/myscript.js">`

If I make React happy, when I run cordova emulate ios, the browser will show this error for all three files.

> Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this
>   server.

If I make Cordova happy, the browser errors disappear, but the app doesn't load - because now React doesn't know what to do with the src.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, ReactJS doesn't change basic browser functionality. When you put `/myApp.js` you're referencing the file from the *root of your server*, and without the slash, you're referencing the path *relative to the currently executing html file*. Omitting the http/https before the // simply tells the browser to follow the same protocol as the current page.

Comment: If you're using ES6 import statements compiled to ES5 by Babel, make sure those "from" paths are correct as well. It would help you to do a hello world ReactJS application in Cordova first, before trying to port your existing application.

Comment: OK cool. I've read that cordova is using file:// so it probably tries to do file://example.com/myscript.js? And as far as I know, cordova builds things out of the www/ directory, and the two local files are in there. It doesn't give any errors on image files though, like <link href="/myImage.png">. What do you suggest?

Comment: What does the Javascript console say?

Comment: When I remove leading slashes and add http:, I'm not getting any errors in the js console. But in the html under <div id="content"> I'm seeing <!-- react-empty: 1 —>

Comment: can we see some code?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to have been with using browserHistory vs hashHistory.

The solution was to keep Cordova happy by removing the leading "/" and adding "http:" and then using

```
const router = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
```